# How to keep Bluetooth connection background?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, background-service

I have created a Bluetooth Activity class in the android app, which works fine for all the Bluetooth functionalities like: scanning, pairing, connecting, sending and receiving data.

The real problem is when the Activity is destroyed. Bluetooth is disconnecting.

how can I make Bluetooth connection throughout the app. and I want to send data to the Bluetooth from other activities.

Help me to implement this in an easy way?

```
public class BTActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<>();
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;
ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> arrayAdapter;

ConnectThread c;

private static final String TAG = "MY_BT";

ListView lvPaired;
Button BluetoothOnOff, ScanBt, pairedlist, sendButton, btDisconnect, incrementBtn, decrementBtn;
EditText input_text;
TextView ConnectedTo;

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

UUID BHANU_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bt);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    lvPaired = findViewById(R.id.btPairedLV);
    pairedlist = findViewById(R.id.btPaired);
    input_text = findViewById(R.id.user_input);
    sendButton = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    BluetoothOnOff = findViewById(R.id.offOn_bt);
    ScanBt = findViewById(R.id.scan_bt);
    ConnectedTo = findViewById(R.id.current_connected_bluetooth);
    btDisconnect = findViewById(R.id.bt_disconnect);
    incrementBtn = findViewById(R.id.incrementBtn);
    decrementBtn = findViewById(R.id.decrementBtn);

    onClickListener();
    pairedList();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

}
public void onClickListener(){

    pairedlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (arrayAdapter != null){
                arrayAdapter.clear();
            }
            pairedList();
        }
    });

    lvPaired.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            c = new ConnectThread(device, true);
            c.start();
        }
    });
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = input_text.getText().toString();
            c.sendData(text);
            input_text.setText("");

        }
    });
    BluetoothOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
                BluetoothOnOff.setText("ON");
            }else {
                mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                BluetoothOnOff.setText("OFF");
            }
        }
    });
    ScanBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ScanFragment scanFragment = new ScanFragment();
            scanFragment.show(fm,"ScanBT");
            //ScanFragment scanFragment = new ScanFragment();
            //scanFragment.show(fm,"Scan Fragment");
        }
    });
    btDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.cancel();
        }
    });

    incrementBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.sendData("a");
        }
    });
    decrementBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.sendData("b");
        }
    });

}


public void toast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void pairedList() {
    //arrayAdapter.clear();
    devices.addAll(mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices());
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, devices);
    lvPaired.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            toast("connected");
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            ConnectedTo.setText(device.getName());
            btDisconnect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //getActionBar().setSubtitle(device.getName());
            Log.d("BT", "connected to");
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            toast("disconnected");
            ConnectedTo.setText("None");
            btDisconnect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           // getActionBar().setSubtitle("");
            Log.d("BT", "disconnected");
        }

    }
};


public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    BluetoothDevice cDevice;
    BluetoothSocket socket;
    ConnectedThread ct;

    ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean insecureConnection) {
        cDevice = device;
        try {
            if (insecureConnection) {
                socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BHANU_UUID);
            } else {
                socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BHANU_UUID);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            Log.d("BT", "Socket ready to connect");
            socket.connect();
            Log.d("BT", "Socket connected");
            // out = socket.getOutputStream();
            // input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        ct = new ConnectedThread(socket);

        //ct.write("Q-smart".getBytes());
            /*try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (final IOException closeException) {
                closeException.getMessage();
            }*/
    }
    private void sendData(String message){
        Log.d(TAG,message);
        if (socket != null){
            ct.write(message.getBytes());
        }else {
            toast("Please connect to bluetooth first");
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
        // member streams are final.
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
        }
        try {
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream.
                numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
               /* Message readMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                        MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                        mmBuffer);
                readMsg.sendToTarget();*/
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);

            // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
           /* Message writtenMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                    MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
            writtenMsg.sendToTarget();*/
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

            // Send a failure message back to the activity.
           /* Message writeErrorMsg =
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("toast",
                    "Couldn't send data to the other device");
            writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);*/
        }
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, I found a working solution for running Bluetooth background in Android.
Below is the code I have used in my android app.

```
public class BluetoothServices extends Service {

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    public static final String B_DEVICE = "MY DEVICE";
    public static final String B_UUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
    // 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;

    private ConnectBtThread mConnectThread;
    private static ConnectedBtThread mConnectedThread;

    private static Handler mHandler = null;
    public static int mState = STATE_NONE;
    public static String deviceName;
    public static BluetoothDevice sDevice = null;
    public Vector<Byte> packData = new Vector<>(2048);

    //IBinder mIBinder = new LocalBinder();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //mHandler = getApplication().getHandler();
        return mBinder;
    }
    public void toast(String mess){
        Toast.makeText(this,mess,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BluetoothServices getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return BluetoothServices.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String deviceg = intent.getStringExtra("bluetooth_device");


        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

                connectToDevice(deviceg);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private synchronized void connectToDevice(String macAddress){
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING){
            if (mConnectThread != null){
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null){
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        mConnectThread = new ConnectBtThread(device);
        toast("connecting");
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }
    private void setState(int state){
        mState = state;
        if (mHandler != null){
           // mHandler.obtainMessage();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void stop(){
        setState(STATE_NONE);
        if (mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null){
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        stopSelf();
    }

    public void sendData(String message){
        if (mConnectedThread!= null){
            mConnectedThread.write(message.getBytes());
            toast("sent data");
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(BluetoothServices.this,"Failed to send data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        setState(STATE_NONE);

        if (mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null){
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

    /*private synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket){

        if (mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null){
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedBtThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();


        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }*/

    private class ConnectBtThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket mSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mDevice;

        public ConnectBtThread(BluetoothDevice device){
            mDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(B_UUID));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mSocket = socket;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                mSocket.connect();
                Log.d("service","connect thread run method (connected)");
                SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("BT_NAME",0);
                pre.edit().putString("bluetooth_connected",mDevice.getName()).apply();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                try {
                    mSocket.close();
                    Log.d("service","connect thread run method ( close function)");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //connected(mSocket);
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedBtThread(mSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
        }

        public void cancel(){

            try {
                mSocket.close();
                Log.d("service","connect thread cancel method");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedBtThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket cSocket;
        private final InputStream inS;
        private final OutputStream outS;

        private byte[] buffer;

        public ConnectedBtThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
            cSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            inS = tmpIn;
            outS = tmpOut;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            int mByte;
            try {
                mByte= inS.read(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("service","connected thread run method");

        }


        public void write(byte[] buff){
            try {
                outS.write(buff);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void cancel(){
            try {
                cSocket.close();
                Log.d("service","connected thread cancel method");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Android does not kill your service after some time (10 hours or so)? I have this problem, thanks.

Comment: How do you access this from my Activities?

Comment: using Ibinder. connect this service to your activity using service connection